# Bcrypt Compare Password

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, bcrypt

I'm having problem in comparing the password and yes it is storing the hash of the password correctly when I'm registering.

Database - MongoDB
I'm using node.js version - v18.17.0
bcrypt version - 5.1.1

Here's my userSchema -

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        if (!this.isModified('password')) {
            return next();
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
        this.password = hashedPassword;
        return next();
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
})
```

also here's my AuthController.js file's login part -

```
loginUser: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = req.body;

            const user = await User.findOne({ email });
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password.' });
            }

            const trimmedPassword = password.trim();

            console.log('Password received:', password);
            console.log('User password:', user.password);

            const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(trimmedPassword, user.password);
            console.log(passwordMatch);

            if (!passwordMatch) {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password.' });
            }

            // Generate a JWT token
            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expireIn: '1h' });

            res.json({ token, userId: user._id, username: user.username });
 } catch(error){...}
```

I'm using postman right now to check it, postman giving me error: 'Invalid email or password', and in the terminal i'm getting -

> Password received: abcd

> User password: $2b$10$3XqxT29oUNX8Sr86i/woPufzHf6s7OjP4yyNdirtGk9Zj0T3MdkAC

> false

Comment: are you sure that the user is correct when accessing `user.password` in your `loginUser`? It seems that you are missing a lookup of the user based on the provided e-mail. Without that lookup, you will not be comparing the correct hash...

Comment: @tucuxi Sorry I shortened the code for clarity, but it seems I missed that crucial part related to finding users by email. I've now added that part back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Savyon, I think I was hashing the password twice so I removed the hashing process from the register code part and made these changes on my user model code -

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        if (!this.isModified('password') || this.isModified('password') && typeof this.password === 'string') {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
            this.password = hashedPassword;
        }
        return next();
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of comparing directly inside `AuthController.js` you can make sure youre accessing the right user by adding a method directly to User model (also make sure bcrypt is imported):

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password);
};
```

once you have relevant user inside `AuthController.js`:

```
const isPasswordVerified = user.comparePassword(payload.password);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @dante did you make sure you didnt encrypt the password twice - once inside `userSchema.pre` and once when you're actually creating the user?  (you didnt share the user creation part)

Comment: After reading your comment I updated and removed the hashing process from the register code and made it do the hashing in User model and it worked. Woohoo! BTW in my user Model I was checking if the password is getting modified then do the hashing but I guess for the registering process it is considered as changing the password. So thanks a lot again and sorry that I didn't provide the whole code before. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
loginUser: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password.' });
        }

        const trimmedPassword = password.trim();
        console.log('Password received:', password);
        console.log('User password:', user.password);

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(trimmedPassword, user.password);
        console.log(passwordMatch);

        if (!passwordMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password.' });
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });

        res.json({ token, userId: user._id, username: user.username });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during the login process.' });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```js
LoginUser = async (req, res) => {
  let success = false;
  // If there are errors, return Bad request and the errors
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      success = false
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
    }

    const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordCompare) {
      success = false
      return res.status(400).json({ success, error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
    }

    const data = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    }

    // console.log("hello   "+ data.user.id)
    const authtoken = jwt.sign(data, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    success = true;
    res.json({ success, authtoken })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.